# What is wrong with this SQLite query?

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause

```
c=MyDB.rawQuery("SELECT Distance FROM " +
            Table1 + "WHERE Source = '" + source + "' AND Distance = " +
                distance + " ' ", null);

distance = c.getFloat(c.getColumnIndex("Distance"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
c=MyDB.rawQuery("SELECT Distance FROM " + Table1 + " WHERE Source = '" + source + "' AND Distance = '" + distance + " ' ", null);
```

Pay attention to the space before `WHERE` keyword and " ' " after Distance = .
Also, better to use not rawQuery, but query method, as it use [prepared statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), which is more safe.

Comment: but you have a quote after the distance.

Comment: May be I am a little late dude, +1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an apostrophe before the distance value, and a space after the table name.

However, this way of constructing queries makes you prone to SQL injection attacks. Instead, use proper parameters. How to do this will be documented in the library you are using.